# Session start in Joomla using a while loop

Tags: php, session, joomla, while-loop

I have 2 databases, one with Joomla installed and the other with my personal data.

I need to work contemporaneously with these 2 databases.

Now I do a `while` into my DB with this query:

```
 $query="Select * From lista where user_id='$id'"; 
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
     $ID_STRUCTURE=$row['ID'];
     ECHO '<P>Modifica <a href="..../test/index.php/modifica">'.$row['struttura'].'</P>';
     $session =& JFactory::getSession();
     $session->set( 'myvar', $ID_STRUCTURE );
 }
```

When I go on the page `/test/index.php/modifica` I use this code:

```
  $session =& JFactory::getSession();
  $myvar= $session->get('myvar');
  echo $myvar;
```

I must obtain only the `$ID_STRUCTURE` of the correspondent `$row['struttura']`.

If I use an array in the `while` and a `foreach` in the other page `/test/index.php/modifica`, I obtain all the values.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do not use mysql_query() anymore! It's deprecated! :) Use PDO or MYsqli instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, because you are always overwrite that in your loop. You need to create an array, or make the key to be unique.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ID_STRUCTURE = $row['ID'];
    ECHO '<P>Modifica <a href="..../test/index.php/modifica">' . $row['struttura'] . '</P>';
    $myvarArray[] = $ID_STRUCTURE;
}
$session = & JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('myvar', $myvarArray);
```

Use mysqli or PDO instead mysql functions since they are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the while loop directly. Store it into an array or variable, so you can use it over and over. Now it's returning you the last value because the while loop already ran. So when you call it again, its already at its last record.

```
$query="Select * FROM `lista` WHERE `user_id` = '$id'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$a_Array = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $a_Array['id'] = $row['ID'];
    $a_Array['link'] = '<P>Modifica <a href="..../test/index.php/modifica">'.$row['struttura'].'</P>';
}
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set( 'myvar', $a_Array);
```

NOW USE A foreach() loop to get all the data on the other page. In that array are the values $myvar['id'] and $myvar['link'].

```
foreach($myvar as $value){
echo $value['id'].$value['link'];
}
```

Comment: COULD YOU GIVE ME AN EXAMPLE PLEASE?

Comment: thanks...so I'm a beginner in php...how can I do foreach() loop in the other page? Consider that to call the session in the other page I use this code:
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
  $myvar= $session->get('myvar');
  echo $myvar;


and I need only the ID_STRUCTURE referred to the structure I click

Comment: @myfriend see updated answer for the foreach. You need to make $myvar the session variable with the array in it just like i showed you in the first example.